# What are the nfs values seen in the Strongarm seciton of features

Tags: features, strongarm

When preparing a feature I see that there are a number of values beginning nfs_ in the Strongarm section.

What are these nfs_ values and do I need them in my feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna go out on a limb and guess that they come from the [Node and Comments Form Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeformsettings), which uses `nfs` as a prefix for variables.

Failing that, have a look through your contributed modules and see what you have that can be shortened to NFS - that's probably the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Clive, that's a big help. Nodeformsettings module